# Nothing rendering in DOM after state change in componentDidMount() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class where I make a GET request with Axios within an async function, then, within a `componentDidMount()` method I set the state with the data returned by the async function.

Within the render method, I have an if/else statement to return null if the state is not set yet, else to render the HTML.

However, nothing is being rendered in the DOM, but there are no errors either. Can someone help me see what am I missing, please?

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {DeleteRequest, GetRequest} from "../../utils/requests";

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            contact: {},
            history: {}
        };
    }

    async getContact() {
        const slug = this.props.match.params.slug
        const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/contacts/" + slug + ".json"

        return GetRequest(url)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getContact()
            .then(resp => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        contact: resp.data.data.attributes,
                        history: resp.data.included
                    }
                )
            })
            .catch( error =>
                console.log(error)
            )
    }

    render() {
        const {contact} = this.state.contact;
        const {history} = this.state.history;

        if (contact === undefined || Object.keys(contact).length === 0) {
            return null
        } else {
            const name = `${contact.first_name} ${contact.last_name}`
            return (
                <div>HI</div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The GetRequest method is:

```js
export const GetRequest = (url) => {

    return axios.get(url)
        .catch( error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Edit:
adding an debugger within `.then` and typing `resp.data.data.attributes` returns this:

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that `contact` is actually a value that should be rendered? E.g. add `console.log('render!', contact)` to your `render()` method for example.

Comment: It says undefined when I do `console.log('render!', contact)`, but I'm guessing is undefined because the promise from the get request hasn't been resolved yet, no? @KelvinSchoofs

Comment: Yes, the first render it should display `undefined`. But your `setState` call should trigger a re-render where, assuming `resp.data.data.attributes` is what you expect, it should print `render!` again, but this time with an actual value instead of `undefined`. If it does keep printing `undefined`, your `resp.data.data.attributes` is probably wrong.

Comment: I have made an edit to the question `resp.data.data.attributes` gives me the right answer

Comment: But does it print `render!` a 2nd time? With the same value as `resp.data.data.attributes`?

Comment: I have put a `render` within the else, before the return, but it throws me an error `cannot read property contact of undefined`, like `this.state` was undefinded

Comment: the problem was that I was defining the state wrong in `const {contact} = this.state.contact;` it was `const {contact} = this.state`

Comment: Ah, now I see it too. I also looked straight over that, _and apparently everyone else who looked at your question in detail._ Might be a good idea to try out TypeScript sometime, it catches things like this.

Comment: yes, definetly! thank you @KelvinSchoofs